# C# - Is there way to copy Console Content and save to file at the end of code as well as have it show up on Console while code is running?

Tags: c#, logging, console, txt

I want to save everything that Console outputs to a .txt file after my code is done executing. I have tried few things like below and it works but while code is running, the console is blank and content is redirected to the file. I would like it to show on console and the file at the same time or at the end of code. Please try and see if you have a better way to do this.

```
            //Saving Console output to file
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter File Name: \n");
            string fileName = Console.ReadLine();

            string filePath = @"C:\Desktop\Log.txt";
            
            FileStream filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
            streamwriter.AutoFlush = true;
            Console.SetOut(streamwriter);
            Console.SetError(streamwriter);
```

Comment: And also when I add this code to the end of my code, only the last output gets redirected to the file and that same line won't show on console. pls help.

Comment: @gunr2171, Serilog sounds brand new, any examples?

Comment: " ... have a better way to do this". Are you saying that your code example is accomplishing what you want?

Comment: Why not using a logging mechanism? Just like serilog as sugested or Log4Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that whenever you write `Console.WriteLine()` you want that message to go to a text file, and also, optionally, to the terminal screen.

So make your own method that does that.

```
static void PrintMessage(string message)
{
    // if you want to print to the screen
    Console.WriteLine(message);

    // if you want to write to a file
    // note, there are more efficient ways to do this
    File.AppendAllText(SomeFilePath, message);

    // if you want more "sinks", then add more here
}
```

Now, in your program, instead of calling `Console.WriteLine` call `PrintMessage`.

---

This answer shows *the fundamentals*. Once you understand, then you can do some research on [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) and other logging libraries.

Comment: thank you. this works perfectly. I am also reading about Serilog, this is thing is amazing.

Comment: The issue is that the "StackOverflowException" is thrown  due to too many recursions. (my case 148)

Answer (score 2):

A @gunr2171 pointed out, there are libraries for this like Serilog and NLog that you can configure to log to both.  The correct approach depends on the scope of your project.  If you are writing something that is going into production, use one of these libraries.  If this is just for a personal/school project, you can do something simple like a Log method that does both like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
  StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();

  private void Log(string msg)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
    this.log.AppendLine(msg);
  }

  ~MyClass() => System.IO.File.AppendAllText("Path\To\File", log.ToString());
}
```

Comment: is this going to log the entire console and what ever is on it after code finishes running?

Comment: Right, this would log to console in real time and then add the same message to a StringBuilder.  Then when you you Finalize (destruct) the class File.AppendText is called which will write all of the text written to the console to the file you specify.  Not knowing the rest of your code there may be a better way to tell when your code finishes running.